# How to disable line breaks in bc?

Tags: bash, line-breaks, bc

Is there a way to disable `bc`'s feature of splitting long numbers into several lines, something like `scale` variable for controlling decimal places? Sure, I can use `sed`, but is there a `bc` way of doing that? Man page at http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html only states that the maximum number of characters per line is 70.

Here's an example of a number being split:

```
bc -l <<< "scale = 100; a(1) * 4"
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\
8164062862089986280348253421170676
```

Comment: You can do it with the shell too with `f=$(bc ...); echo "${f/$'\\\\\n'/}"` just for the record.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [online bc man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html#SEC23) doesn't match what I have under "Environment Variables"; the man page for my version (v1.06.95) dated 2006-06-11 claims that you can set BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 to disable line breaks, as a GNU-specific extension:

> BC_LINE_LENGTH
>
> This should be an integer specifying the number of characters in an output line for numbers. This includes the backslash and newline characters for long numbers.  As an extension, the  value  of zero disables the multi-line feature.  Any other value of this variable that is less than 3 sets the line length to 70.

You can set BC_LINE_LENGTH as an environment variable in your shell, or inline preceding the call to `bc`:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l <<< "scale = 100; a(1) * 4"
```

---

**Epilogue:** After some sleuthing, it seems that though gnu.org's latest version is [v1.06](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bc/) dated 2000-11-15 and matching the documentation published above, there are [new upstream versions (v1.06.94 and v1.06.95)](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/bc/) hosted on alpha.gnu.org. These newer versions contain the BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 feature.

See the [Debian-specific bug report and patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=245899) created in 2004 and published in 2007 (!) that adds this extension, as well as [Debian's bc changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/b/bc/bc_1.06.95-9_changelog). It appears this should be available in modern versions of Debian and Ubuntu, but may not appear for other distributions.

In older implementations, picking an arbitrary large number (`BC_LINE_LENGTH=5000`) will likely get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks, it works: `export BC_LINE_LENGTH=0; bc -l <<< "scale = 100; a(1) * 4"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `read` (*without* the usually recommended `-r` flag) to grab the value as one uninterrupted line.

```
$ read pi <<< "$(bc -l <<< "scale = 100; a(1) * 4")"
$ echo $pi
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170676
```

or

```
read pi < <(bc -l <<< "scale = 100; a(1) * 4))
```

(It's not `bc`, sure, but it's more efficient than calling `sed`.)

Comment: Awesome! It's very simple and easy to remember, thanks!